# Enable javascript in C# webview

Tags: javascript, c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I want to enable Javascript in C# webview. But I am unable to do so.

It is giving "Javascript error."

Please help.

Please find the error below.

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser2.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");

        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: It's time to move to WebView2 component: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use geckofx, it's better than webview:
64 bit: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geckofx60.64/
32 bit: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geckofx60.32/